# Get Authorization Token through C# code

Tags: box-api

How do I get Authorization code pragmatically using Box.V2 API? I need to get it through C# code so that I can reuse it to generate refresh and access token through code.

Right now, I need to generate first refresh token manually and then next tokens are generated. I want to automate this as well.

I am looking for a way which can be used in a class library also.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Box V2 API uses OAuth2, you must retrieve the access/refresh tokens through a web browser/web view.

The closest thing I've heard to automating this process is using webview and then manipulating the dom to populate the respective fields. This of course is not recommended.

Any particular reason you cannot generate the initial set of access/refresh tokens, then on each